# MaterialDatePicker and TimePickerDialog are styled differently when using dark theme

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I currently use MaterialDatePicker, and because the material team isn't working on the corresponding TimePicker, I've chosen to use TimePickerDialog.

```
val calendarConstraints = CalendarConstraints.Builder().setOpenAt(datetimeAsUTC)
val datePicker: MaterialDatePicker<Long> = MaterialDatePicker
       .Builder
       .datePicker()
       .setSelection(datetimeAsUTC)
       .setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraints.build())
       .setTitleText(label)
       .build()

datePicker.show(requireFragmentManager(), datePicker.toString())
```

```
val timePicker : TimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), { _, hour, minute ->
        vm.process(event(hour, minute))
    },
    datetime.value?.hourOfDay ?: 0,
    datetime.value?.minuteOfHour ?: 0,
    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(requireContext())
)           
timePicker.show()
```

They work great, but their styling doesn't match under dark theme

[image]

This seems like an issue a lot of people would have run into, so hopefully there's an easy solution.
I could try to change the colors myself, but I don't have a lot of experience with this, and considering
I'm not looking for a custom look, but a standard one that would match other apps, I think there's a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `MaterialTimePicker` in the Material Compoments Library:

```
val materialTimePicker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
    .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
    .setHour(22)
    .setMinute(10)
    .build()

materialTimePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "fragment_tag")
```

**Note:** this code requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha03`**.

[image]